# PHP/JS : Auto click button in iframe when its opened

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to auto click a button in iframe (to add an article to the cart) when its opened from the result page.

My code is working but the page is loading forever and it keep adding to the cart without stopping.

RESULT PAGE :

```
<form>
<a href='#cart'>Add</a>
<div id='cart'>
<iframe src="http://domaine.com/inframe.php" name = 'myIframe' ></iframe>
</div>
</form>
```

IFRAME:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='submit' id ="iframeAdd" name='iframeAdd' value='ADD'>
<input  type='hidden' name='quantity'>
<input type='hidden' name='item' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='price' value='20' />
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('iframeAdd').click();
}
</script>
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['iframeAdd'] ) ) {
echo 'ADDED !';
} else echo 'ERROR';
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting form (causing page to reload) while performing `click()` action. You need to check if form was submitted in javascript. E.g.:

```
<form action='?submitted' method='post'>
<input type='submit' id ="iframeAdd" name='iframeAdd' value='ADD'>
<input  type='hidden' name='quantity'>
<input type='hidden' name='item' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='price' value='20' />
<script>
  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
window.onload = function(){
  if(getParameterByName('submitted') === null){
    document.getElementById('iframeAdd').click();
  }
}

</script>
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['iframeAdd'] ) ) {
echo 'ADDED !';
} else echo 'ERROR';
?>
</form>
```

It adds get parameter `submitted` after first form submit & checks in javascript if this parameter is set (if it's not set - performs button click)

Comment: The page is not loading indefinitely anymore, but every manual page loading adds all articles to the cart...